# authentification des membres de développement de l'API wordpress

Tags: wordpress, authentication

I am creating my community (Wordpress site) around a game (Habbo). To avoid identity theft, I would like to create the same user verification system to register on my site as the site https://habbgames.fr/register
their system generates a code to be inserted into the player's profile on the game in question (habbo), thanks to this, the person who registers must insert this code in his mission (personal message field in the game) to to be able to continue the registration in correspondence with his nickname identical to that of the game. Could you guide me on the procedure to follow? help will be very kind ☺️
I have a git file with all the game's public API data: https://github.com/gerbenjacobs/HabboAPI

Comment: Translate your question title - otherwise people will skip your question.